# Grails test-app is not executing statement

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I am writing unit test case for service class. There is one method called 
getMemberStatusAndCurrentProducts. I have full filled both the conditions but still it is not executing inner statements of this condition.

```
Map getMemberStatusAndCurrentProducts(Member member) {
        def results = [:]

        results.memberId = member.id
        results.firstName = member.contactInfo.firstName
        results.lastName = member.contactInfo.lastName
        results.status = member.status
        results.email = member.contactInfo.email

        if (member.status == MemberStatusType.EXPIRED) {
            results.products = (member.activeEnrollments.originatingOffer*.products)?.flatten()?.unique()?.sort() { it.name }
            results.offerGroup = (member.activeEnrollments.originatingOffer*.offerGroup)?.flatten()?.unique()?.sort() { it?.name }
        } else {
            results.products = (member.activeEnrollments.originatingOffer*.products)?.flatten()?.unique()?.sort() { it.name }
            results.offerGroup = (member.activeEnrollments.originatingOffer*.offerGroup)?.flatten()?.unique()?.sort() { it?.name }
        }

        return results
    }
```

The if condition is shown covered but these statements are shown as uncovered

```
if (member.status == MemberStatusType.EXPIRED) {
            results.products = (member.activeEnrollments.originatingOffer*.products)?.flatten()?.unique()?.sort() { it.name }
            results.offerGroup = (member.activeEnrollments.originatingOffer*.offerGroup)?.flatten()?.unique()?.sort() { it?.name }
        } else {
            results.products = (member.activeEnrollments.originatingOffer*.products)?.flatten()?.unique()?.sort() { it.name }
            results.offerGroup = (member.activeEnrollments.originatingOffer*.offerGroup)?.flatten()?.unique()?.sort() { it?.name }
        }
```

Where activeEnrollments is method of Member domain, originatingOffer is an object of Offer domain. I am using `test-app -coverage :unit <service_class>` command to run unit test.

Can anyone help me in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Every time the '?' operator is used, a new branch condition is introduced because it's performing a null check.  So in order to cover all the branch conditions in this statement

`results.products = (member.activeEnrollments.originatingOffer*.products)?.flatten()?.unique()?.sort() { it.name }`

you need to write a test where
`(member.activeEnrollments.originatingOffer*.products)` returns null/empty, a test where `(member.activeEnrollments.originatingOffer*.products)?.flatten()` returns null/empty, and a test where `(member.activeEnrollments.originatingOffer*.products)?.flatten()?.unique()` returns null/empty.

I don't see how unique() could ever return null/empty in this case, so I'd suggest getting rid of that check.